# Error:(30, 18) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-support-library, android-support-design

I have already add the "maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}" but it doesn't work
This is my build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

And this is my other build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.quizapp.conte.quizapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    debugCompile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
I tried everything and I do not know what to do.
I started the project recently so i didn't modify other files exept the build.gradle.
Thank you all.

Comment: can you use google()  instead of the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:(30, 18) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1

It happens because this dependency **doesn't exist**.

Use

```
debugCompile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

instead of

```
debugCompile 'com.android.support:design-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but i have another error now: 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

Comment: It happens because you are using different versions of firebase and google play services libraries (11.8.0 and10.2.0). Use the same version 11.8.0 or 10.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In new Gradle version(4.1+), you must use google repository like below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

       }
}
```

If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
         maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'

           }
    }
```

Comment: It is not correct.You can use in any case  `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`. The `google()` repo is a shortcut to looks in Google's Maven repository for dependencies. It was introduced with gradle v.4.0.